# Postman giving me a JSON Bad String Error

Tags: json, postman

I'm new to Postman- I am inserting a report and calling  this function with a POST and Body JSON like this:

```html
{
"data": [
 {
prmRoadClosures : "I-65",
prmFirstMaintainStart=: "Test_EMS",
prmPSR_AbnormalOperations: "Test AO",
prmFeedstockChanges: "Test FSC",
prmLineupChanges: "Test LC",
prmSafetyMeetings: "Test_SM",
prmAR_SH_ID: 1,
prmAR_RE_ID : 1,
prmCR_AbnormalOperations : "Test AO",
prmHighPriorityAlarms : "Test HPA",
prmImpairment_to_fire_protection_systems : "Test Fire systems",
prmAlarmsInhibited : "test ALARMS",
prmCR_OP_ID : 1,
prmCR_PC_ID : 1,
prmFR_AbnormalOperations : "Test AO",
prmMaintenance : "test M",
prmFR_OP_ID : "1",
prmBP_ID : 1,
prmDP_ID : 1,
prmEQM_ID : 1,
prmCreatedDate : ,
prmUpdatedDate : ,
prmCreatedBy : "HS",
prmUpdatedBy : "HS",
prmShift : "1",
prmArea_ID : 1,
prmUser_ID : 1
 }
 ]
}
```

the Bad Script error show

```html
prmRoadClosures : "I-65",
```

to be the offending line. I can't see why I'm getting this error.  Is it obvious?

TIA
Harry

Comment: Shouldn't `prmRoadClosures : "I-65",` be `"prmRoadClosures" : "I-65",` ? (check the double quotes around member name)

Comment: Did you try putting "prmRoadClosures" and others in quotes?

Comment: Maybe this is the line with the error: `prmFirstMaintainStart=: "Test_EMS",` - look the `=` sign. Also, check the values of `prmCreatedDate` and `prmUpdatedDate`.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I needed "" around keys.  Also cleaned up the other.  What do I do for parameter that are blank?

Answer (score 4):

That's not JSON Format like previously said.
If you have doubt on json format, you can use a validator like : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

It will find error for each row so that's really helpful to find all mistakes.